# Paperclip: copy_to_local_file called upon every update (of unrelated attributes)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm using paperclip 4.1.0 with Amazon S3.
I was wondering why requests were so slow and found that "copy_to_local_file" is called whenever I am updating attributes of a model with an attachment, even if it's just one attribute unrelated to the attachment (in my case, a cache_count, which means that every time someone votes an instance up, the attachment is downloaded locally!).

I understand it is used in case a rollback is required, but it seems overkill when the attribute isn't directly related to the attachment.

Am I using paperclip in the wrong way or is it something that could be improved ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I am stuck with same problem, did you come up with any solution?

Comment: Didn't have time to test it but did just now, posted the answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an issue with paperclip, it's fixed on the master branch!

Comment: Yes, it is fixed in 4.1.1. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just my 2 cents:
the attachment gets downloaded locally only after `ActiveRecord::Base#save` is called.

1. Would calling the 'base#save' in a cron on a daily basis instead help with the load?
2. Otherwise, either remove the calling of method `copy_to_local_file` if possible
3. or editing the source of paperclip's method of copy_to_local_file(style, local_dest_path) to exclude the downloading of attachment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll award the bounty for the effort, but I don't feel like this solves the issue in a clean way, it's feels like a lot of efforts for something that should be trivial.